# Including logo when sending email via postal

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, postal

In my MVC4 application, I am using the postal package for sending emails.

I am trying to include a logo via an `<img>` tag, but it's not working.

How can I include my company logo?

**Controller Action**:

```
   public ActionResult Index()
   {
       dynamic email = new Email("Example");
       email.To = "xxxxx@xxxxxx";
       email.FunnyLink = "haiii";
       email.Send();
       return View();
   }
```

**View**:

```
 To: @ViewBag.To From: lolcats@website.com 
 Subject: Important Message 

 <div style="background-color:aqua;">
     Hello, You wanted important web links right?
     Check out this: @ViewBag.FunnyLink

     <br />
     <img src="~/Images/Logo.png" />
 </div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use full absolute image urls like this-

```
<img src="@Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority)/Images/Logo.png" />
```

or

If you're having html based files then you should send the domain name just like the other data you're passing into the view like this-

```
<img src="@ViewBag.DomainName/Images/Logo.png" />
```

When your email would be received by the users then the content of your email would not resolve the image path from relative urls like this -

```
/Images/logo.png {this will not work}
```

So the images can only be fetched if having full domain path.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Html extension as shown below.  You can refer [here](https://kirandhappuri.wordpress.com/2015/09/13/sending-email-with-a-background-image-using-postal-asp-net-mvc/) for more details.

```
<div style="background-color:aqua;">
    Hello, You wanted important web links right?
    Check out this: @ViewBag.FunnyLink

   <br />
    @Html.EmbedImage("~/Images/Logo.png")
</div>
```